# How to determine if printer can print to pdf file? c#

Tags: c#, winapi

I need to get a list of all installed printers that can print into a PDF file.
I already can get list of all installed printers using `System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters`
but how to filter only those that can print into PDF file?

Comment: You can not know, the print to PDF feature is inmplemented in the printer drivers. You could look at the printer properties and look for those a physical printer would have (bout you would not know the different between "Microsoft Print to PDF" and "Microsoft XPS Document Writer")

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve here? If you actually want to "print" something, then the user should select the printer. If you want to save some data as a pdf document there are other ways to do it.